# How to implement base b expansion in Python?

Tags: python, radix, expansion

I have to implement this pseudo-code (from a discrete math book):

procedure *base b expansion(n,b: positive integers with b>1*

```
q :=n
k :=0

while q does not equal 0
    a_k := q mod b
    q = q div b
    k = k + 1
```

return `(a_k-1, .... a_1, a_0)` `{(a_k-1... a_1a_0)_b is the base expansion of n}`

Here is my code thus far:

```
def expansion(n,b):
    q = n
    k = 0
    a = []
    i = len(str(n))

    for x in range(0,1000):
        a.append(0)

    while q != 0:
        a[k] = q % b
        q = q / b

    return a[k]

print expansion(444,2)
```

I just cant figure out what I am doing wrong, it usually says the index is out of bounds or it doesn't print enough numbers.

Comment: Please do not remove the contents of your question once it has been answered.  It removes the value for future users who find it when visiting the site.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are not updating `k`,

```
while q != 0:
    a[k] = q % b
    q = q / b

    # You need to update k
    k += 1
```

Also, you need to return only `a`, **not** `a[k]`.

Also, understand that for the current argument (`444`,`2`) you need at least `1085` places in the array before `q` becomes zero. You do not need to assign based on an index, but rather append the values to the list as they are computed.

So,

```
def expansion(n,b):
    q = n
    k = 0
    a = []
    i = len(str(n))

    while q != 0:
        a.append(q % b)
        q = q / b
        k += 1

    return a
```

This way you avoid having to allocate places before hand.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a list to accumulate digits, try a string. As you get a digit, concatenate it to the front of the string. Like so:

```
>>> def n_as_base_b(n, b):
...     output = ""
...     while n >0:
...             output = str(n%b) + output
...             n /= b
...     return output
... 
>>> n_as_base_b(15,2)
'1111'
>>> n_as_base_b(11,2)
'1011'
```

Comment: I don't think the result will make a lot of sense this way.

Comment: I'm not sure how it makes sense any other way. See edited answer.

Comment: The returned value should be a list instead of a string. (Otherwise, what does the output `'10'` mean when `b = 37`?)